# How does one fix an interleaved data set from only sampling one data set?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

The following

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from datasets import interleave_datasets

# Preprocess each dataset
c4 = load_dataset("c4", "en", split="train", streaming=True) 
wikitext = load_dataset("wikitext", "wikitext-103-v1", split="train", streaming=True)

# Interleave the preprocessed datasets  
datasets = [c4, wikitext]
for dataset in datasets:
  print(dataset.description)
interleaved = interleave_datasets(datasets, probabilities=[0.5, 0.5])
print(interleaved)
```

only samples from one data set, why?

```
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
example.keys()=dict_keys(['text', 'timestamp', 'url'])
counts=100
```

colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VIR66U1d7qk3Q1vU_URoo5tHEEheORpN?usp=sharing

---

cross:

- hf discord: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1138632039197835354
- hf discuss: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-does-one-fix-an-interleaved-data-set-from-only-sampling-one-data-set/50041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `interleave_datasets` function works correctly here, it's your conclusion that is incorrect. What happens is that when two datasets are interleaved, their features are combined.

These are the features of `c4` and `wikitext`:

```py
print(c4.column_names)

>>> ['text', 'timestamp', 'url']

print(wikitext.column_names)

>>> ['text']
```

When you combine the datasets, all examples in the new dataset will have features `['text', 'timestamp', 'url']`, even if they come from `wikitext` dataset. Since `wikitext` dataset does not have features `timestamp` and `url`, these will be `None`.

Dummy example:

```py
from datasets import Dataset, interleave_datasets
d1 = Dataset.from_dict({
  'feature_1': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})
d2 = Dataset.from_dict({
  'feature_2': [1, 2, 3]
})

dataset = interleave_datasets([d1, d2], probabilities=[0.5, 0.5], seed=42)
print('Features:', dataset.column_names)

for e in dataset:
  print(e)
```

Output:

```
Features: ['feature_1', 'feature_2']
{'feature_1': None, 'feature_2': 1}
{'feature_1': 'A', 'feature_2': None}
{'feature_1': None, 'feature_2': 2}
{'feature_1': None, 'feature_2': 3}
```